# Formatting measure based on dimension attribute

Tags: ssas, mdx

This may be very basic. I'm trying to change the format string used on a measure based on the attribute of a dimension connected to the measure. I'm doing this in a calculated measure at the moment.

Essentially, the fact table row contains a value for the ID of the dimension, and that dimension has the format information I want. I'd like to apply formatting based on that value, without the dimension being required in my query.

something like this:

```
WHEN [Format Source].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Properties("Format") is [Format Source].[Format].&[Number (123)]
THEN FORMAT([Measures].[Volume], "#.#")
```

I'd like this formatting to be applied regardless of having the dimension in the query, as I won't always have control over how the reports the users create. The data could be whole number or % with differing levels of decimal precision, based on the attribute of the format dimension.

I think that I may just be way off on this one, thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197407/defining-a-calculated-member-in-mdx-filtering-a-measures-value). The only thing you need to figure out is how to set the value of `format_string` based on the current member.