# SQL MDX to Excel MDX to create a Calculated Measure

Tags: excel, mdx, measure

I have the following query created on SQL Management studio and I'm trying to use it in a Calculated Measure in Excel:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Net Cash Invoice Sales] } ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Customer].[Customer Type].&[Existing Guest] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Model]) WHERE ( [Customer].[Customer Type].&[Existing Guest] )
```

I have tried different options but cant get the right syntax so it works in Excel MDX. The Measure is a simple selection of Invoices by a customer type.

so something like:
[Measures].[Net Cash Invoice Sales]
WHERE ( [Customer].[Customer Type].&[Existing Guest] )

I tried using Functions like Filter but no go:

Filter
(
[Measures].[Net Cash Invoice Sales]
,
[Customer].[Customer Type].&[Existing Guest]
)

Answer (score 0):

Who knew it could be so simple?

```
([Measures].[Net Cash Invoice Sales],
[Customer].[Customer Type].[Existing Guest])
```

Got the idea from
[Define a calculated member in MDX by filtering a measure's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197407/define-a-calculated-member-in-mdx-by-filtering-a-measures-value)